# Cannot get order history from google play market

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to get my orders that i made in InApp billing ,but each time i try it gives me null. In play.google.com the items that i bought are in order history,but when i check in mPurchaseMap it is null.

My method :

```
 @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e("Android", "Problem getting inventory " + result.getMessage() + " code: " + result.getResponse());
            } else {
                Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(Constants.SKU_PREMIUM_ACCOUNT);
                if(premiumPurchase != null)
                {
                    Log.e("Android", "User is premium");
                    SmokingUtils.changeToPremiuimAccount(getActivity());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("Android", "User is NOT premium");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you've logged into play store with the same account with which you see history on play.google.com?

Comment: yes im on the same accout